# Regex for matching attribute values in invalid xml file

Tags: c#, regex, xml, parsing, escaping

I have some invalid XML's ( < > & "" characters inside the attribute value). I need to parse them to a correct XML file in C#.

The only way I can think of is escaping the invalid characters inside the attributes. This works fine for < > and & (&lt ;, &gt ;, &amp ;). However I have problems detecting and changing the "" inside the attributes.

Right now I am using this regex for matching attribute values:

```
/="(.*?)"
```

My test case is this:

```
<add sqlQuery="select blaat from test where count == "1"" test="dfsdf"/>
<add sqlQuery="select blaat from test where count == "1"" test="dfsdf" />
<add sqlQuery="select blaat from test where count == "1" and blaat > 3" test="dfsdf"/>
<add xmlDiff_action="MoveNodeFrom('1')" alias="jkhkjh" />
<add xmlDiff_action="MoveNodeFrom('1')" />
```

[RegEx test link with not greedy](http://regex101.com/r/cD7iL2/1)

As you can see in the test the matching stops at the quote "1""

If I change the regex to greedy **/="(.*)"** I match the whole line (so including the other attributes on the same line.

[RegEx test link with greedy:](http://regex101.com/r/cD7iL2/2)

It is hard to define the "end quote" of an xml attribute.
In my test cases it can end in:

- " (space)
- "/>
- "
- " otherAttribute="value"

I know that the it looks unnecessary that I want to parse this invalid xml (even invalid sql query because it uses double spaces and quotes for == "1". Thas is because it comes from another application which saves all the data in a CDATA section.
But for what I am doing I need to parse that CDATA section into correct XML (with escaping the invalid characters)

Huge thanks in advance if somebody could solve this in RegEx or combination of RegEx and C#!

Comment: Where do these not-quite-XML files come from? If at *all* possible, I'd try to fix the problem at its source rather than trying to handle the outcome. If the problem is due to someone else's code, you should *at least* express your displeasure with them. It's worrying when you see things like this, as it suggests they're producing XML by hand (rather than using an XML API) - it makes me wonder what else they're doing that's a really bad idea.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to just match the invalid values? What other cases but `"1"` are possible"? If it's not `="1"` but `== "1"` then it's invalid and shold be fixed... mhmmm

Comment: Not that easy. Cannot change where the source XML comes from. The XML further is totally variable with no real logic. Even found attributes that have a whole new XML document inside them, including xml declaration.... Also, we are talking about "XML" files over 100.000 lines of xml...

Comment: For starters, please don't refer to this stuff as XML. It will only get people confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that the SQL statement is expected inside params, we could come to the following regexp using captured groups:

```
(?<match>"((\g<match>|[^"]*))*?")(?=\s|\/|>)/gm
```

[Proof](http://regex101.com/r/kY0bS8/1) somehow works, but it’s insane to even try those regexps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. It seems to work in the tests. I know this is pretty insane but right now I don't see another way. I cannot change the source where the invalid XML comes from.

Comment: Was glad to help, but, please, never mention I shared the code catching SQL inside invalid XML parameters with you :)

Comment: Haha, ok. Yeah, is not nice coding but sometimes you can't change it. Especially in a short time.

One question, something I didn't experience before:
My Regex parse (Matches) takes forever (never ending) in .NET while if I parse the whole document online it goes very fast finding and marking all the attributes.

Any idea where to start looking?

I escaped the RegEx string in C# like:
string regexCondition = "(?<match>\"((\\g<match>|[^\"]*))*?\")(?=\\s|\\/)/gm";
Regex regex = new Regex(regexCondition, RegexOptions.Compiled);

Comment: Sorry, I never worked with regexps in C#, but I can’t find in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) whether `/gm` modifiers are allowed. Shouldn’t you use `Regex.Multiline` etc instead? Escaping looks reasonable to me.

Comment: I found the problem why it takes so long. Your regEx works perfectly except it goes wrong when the tag ends on > instead of "space" >

http://regex101.com/r/kY0bS8/3

I am trying to fix that problem but it is hard for me. (meaning: trying without real understanding). If you would have the time to take a fast look I would be very thankful!

Comment: Simply add `|>` for “or followed by greater sign” to lookforward condition. http://regex101.com/r/bX7yQ8/1 + updated an answer.